# php-cordova: secure backend files

Tags: php, cordova

I am using **cordova** to create a android app and i am using **php-mysql** as backend.

I am fetching/sending data from database by ajax.
As you know we can't fetch the data directly due to **CORS** issue. 
to fetch the data remotly we need to add
 `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Problem is it makes my backend exposed. Because any one can try to fetch the data from backend. Which i don't want.

Please advise how can i make it secure.

Thanks

Comment: Is your backend a rest service? By the way, do it through HTTPS protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` from your backend service.

After that for your cordova application you need to install [whitelist plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) and to config it.

Add this in your config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

Include **Content-Security-Policy** meta in your html page.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data:">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try.